# JSON internet explorer problems

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, parsing

I am using GalleryCMS which outputs a JSON feed for images captions etc.  Using this as a separate script to parse JSON:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.gallerycms = function( options ) {

    var settings = $.extend({
      url : '',
      theme : '',
    }, options);

    var $this = $(this);

    return this.each(function() {

      if (settings.url.indexOf('/myfeed/') > -1) {
        alert('Only album feeds are supported by Galleria.')
      } else if (settings.url.indexOf('/feed/') > -1) {
        parseAlbum();
      }

    });

    function parseAlbum() {  
      $.getJSON(settings.url, 
                function(data) {
        $.each(data.images, function(key, image) {
          $($this).append('img src=<a href="' + image.url + '"><img data-title="' + image.caption + '" src="' + image.thumb + '" /></a>');
        });

        Galleria.loadTheme(settings.theme);
        Galleria.run($this);
      });
    }

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Within the html document I use this to set script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#galleria').gallerycms({
        url : 'http://www.paulgubaphoto.com/GalleryCMS/index.php/api/feed/json/e2b740b7-9ab1-11e1-ae3d-0022192d6244',
        theme : '/galleria/themes/twelve/galleria.twelve.min.js'
      });
```

So works perfectly with Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Mozilla but no love with internet explorer.
You can find it here: www.paulgubaphoto.com/index-test.html.  I am a rank beginner so please type slowly and clearly.

Paul

Comment: What's the error in IE ?

Comment: I get no error message images just don't load or appear.  I don't own a windows machine so difficult for me to trouble shoot.  I am using adobe browser lab at least to see if its loading images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your document.ready function call to initialize gallerycms you are using the web service URL `http://paulgubaphoto.com/GalleryCMS/index.php/api/feed/json/3e346db5-93b0-11e1-ae3d-0022192d6244`.  However the request is coming from `http://www.paulgubaphoto.com/index-test.html`.  IE is seeing "www.paulgubaphoto.com and "paulgubaphoto.com" as 2 different sites. This means that (in IE at least) your web service request is subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (see Origin determination rules) and would require use of jsonp.  If you actually change the domain of the URL in the browser address bar to match the domain part of the web query URL everything works (at least on my version of IE9).

In order to avoid the need to use jsonp you should try to define your gallerycms web service URL as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#galleria').gallerycms({
        url : 'http://' + document.domain + '/GalleryCMS/index.php/api/feed/json/3e346db5-93b0-11e1-ae3d-0022192d6244',
        theme : '/galleria/themes/twelve/galleria.twelve.min.js'
      });
```

That way you don't have to worry about such issues.

Comment: Sorry amended the script to "mysite.com"  There are not calls outside my domains.  Everything is contained within the domain.  Images, GalleryCMS, javascripts, html are all in paulgubaphoto.com

Comment: If you replace your entire $.getJSON call with `$.ajax({url: settings.url}).error(function(a,b,c){alert(b+": "+c);});` do you see an alert dialog?  If so, what does it show?

Comment: So nothing happened when replacing that other then the script doesn't work.  Though not entirely sure I followed your directions correctly.  Keep in mind I am a complete beginner so I am fumbling through this and maybe learning at the same time.

Comment: I don't know if this will fix your problem (don't think so, since it doesn't look like you're even posting), but I noticed that the content type of the json your web service returns is text/javascript.  It should be "application/json; charset=utf-8".

Comment: I looked through the source code of your homepage and noticed that in the call to gallerycms you have set the dataType & contentType.  Those property data don't get picked up by the underlying getJSON call in galleria.gallerycms.js.  The content-type will need to be set by the web service method.  I'm not familiar with php, but [this page](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/php-headers-serve-json) seems to have what you need.

Comment: By the way, you can look at the content-type yourself (in FireFox) by pasting `http://www.paulgubaphoto.com/GalleryCMS/index.php/api/feed/json/e2b740b7-9ab1-11e1-ae3d-0022192d6244` into the browser bar, then right click and choose View Page Info.

Comment: Thanks Mark I was kinda thinking the same thing but did not know where to apply it.  Would this be in the GalleryCMS that creates the JSON data or within the javascript that parses it?  In my reading other post almost all issues with JSON and IE this is a common problem.

Comment: Well was able to figure how to set JSON feed to json/application but still no love with IE at least with Adobe Browser Lab.

Comment: I think I found your problem. See my updated (rewritten) answer.

Comment: Well I tried putting the link to JSON feed into Adobe Browser Lab and it would not load internet explorer all others it did.

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite follow that.  1st step to check my revised answer is to use `http://paulgubaphoto.com/index-test.html` (no "www") as the URL and see if your page works in IE.

Comment: Yes it works that without the "www" In adobe browser lab. Why is that I wonder?

Comment: Please see my revised answer and explanatory link.

Comment: OK that makes sense.  However I unsure of the implementation using: url: 'http://' + document.domain + '/GalleryCMS/index.php/api/feed/json/3e346db5-93b0-11e1-ae3d-0022192d6244'

Comment: You need to do it in the document.ready function.  See my updated answer .

Comment: Brillant worked!!!  So just a "www" is causing the error.  Now is there a reason we would want this to happen typically.

Comment: Super.  Glad I could help.  Please don't forget to mark this as the answer when you get the chance.